# MS SQL Server 2008 query - doesn't get proper send and received message count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    U.UserId as 'Id', 
    U.FullName as 'Name',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Conversation] 
     WHERE FromUserId = 'user1' AND ToUserId = U.UserId) 'SentCount',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Conversation] 
     WHERE ToUserId = 'user1' AND FromUserId = U.UserId) 'ReceivedCount'
FROM 
    [Conversation] C 
INNER JOIN 
    [User] U ON U.UserId = C.FromUserId
WHERE 
    C.ToUserId = 'user1'
```

Query returns a result but it doesn't include some of the rows. `Conversation` table contains the same `FromUserId` (send message user) and `ToUserId` (receive message user).

Here are the tables :

[image]

Current result -

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Table with dummy data -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [UserId] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](11) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[User] ([Id], [UserId], [Name], [Email]) VALUES (1, N'user1', N'user1', N'user1@a.com')
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([Id], [UserId], [Name], [Email]) VALUES (2, N'user2', N'user2', N'user2@a.com')
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([Id], [UserId], [Name], [Email]) VALUES (3, N'user3', N'user3', N'user3@a.com')
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([Id], [UserId], [Name], [Email]) VALUES (4, N'user4', N'user4', N'user4@a.com')
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([Id], [UserId], [Name], [Email]) VALUES (5, N'user5', N'user5', N'user5@a.com')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Conversation](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [conversationId] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [messageId] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [fromUserId] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [toUserId] [varchar](5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[Conversation] ([Id], [conversationId], [messageId], [fromUserId], [toUserId]) VALUES (1, N'con-user1user2', N'mes1', N'user1', N'user2')
INSERT [dbo].[Conversation] ([Id], [conversationId], [messageId], [fromUserId], [toUserId]) VALUES (2, N'con-user1user2', N'mes2', N'user1', N'user2')
INSERT [dbo].[Conversation] ([Id], [conversationId], [messageId], [fromUserId], [toUserId]) VALUES (3, N'con-user2user1', N'mes3', N'user2', N'user1')
INSERT [dbo].[Conversation] ([Id], [conversationId], [messageId], [fromUserId], [toUserId]) VALUES (4, N'con-user1user3', N'mes4', N'user1', N'user3')
INSERT [dbo].[Conversation] ([Id], [conversationId], [messageId], [fromUserId], [toUserId]) VALUES (5, N'con-user4user1', N'mes5', N'user4', N'user1')
```

Can someone help how to includes all the records?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide table structure and sample data that reproduces the problem (e.g. show us a row that you think should have been included but was not). You can do this [at `db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019).

Comment: A `DISTINCT` and a `GROUP BY` in a query that contains no aggregation (the aggregation in the sub queries is in a different scope) suggests something is very wrong here. Having a `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` in the same query normally means your `GROUP BY` is wrong (as the `GROUP BY` should already be returning rows for distinct groups), and a query with a `GROUP  BY` and no aggregation normally means the `GROUP BY` isn't needed.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  updated table structure

Comment: Are there foreign keys on Conversation.FromUserId and Conversation.ToUserId?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft no

Comment: @Larnu correct does matter group by - removed it and updated question again.

Comment: Again, can you show enough data that demonstrates a row you think should be counted but isn't? We have no idea why you _think_ the first row should be sent = 2 and received = 1. Show us the data that leads you to that expected result (and how the query returned a different result).

Comment: You expect `User4` in the result, but is it excluded because there have only been messages _in one direction_? `WHERE C.ToUserId = 'user1'` means you're only looking at rows where `user1` *received* a message.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `join` in the outer query.  This would be more simply written as:

```
SELECT U.UserId as Id, U.FullName as Name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM [Conversation] c
     WHERE c.FromUserId = 'user1' AND c.ToUserId = U.UserId
    ) as SentCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM [Conversation] c 
     WHERE c.ToUserId = 'user1' AND c.FromUserId = U.UserId
    ) as ReceivedCount
FROM [User] U ;
```

Notes:

- Qualify all column references.  This is particularly important for correlation clauses.
- Give tables aliases that are abbreviations for the table names.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Do not use the for column aliases.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fff141f37803bf69a3bba9948f2d4d32) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I need where condition to select a particular user and the above query gives me to send/received count as zero

Comment: @NileshMistry One more time: please provide sample data along with your desired results.

Comment: @NileshMistry . . . Your desired results show rows for what looks like all users.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have generated test data with script. how to give it to you ?

Comment: @NileshMistry . . . If it is small, add it to the question.  You can also set up a db<>fiddle with the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  updated data and script on the question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand provided data and updated expected and actual results. I will have to script work in both directions.

Comment: @NileshMistry . . . This answer does what you want.  I included a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218910/discussion-between-nilesh-mistry-and-gordon-linoff).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the conversation table at your base select. Something like this would work, but can be optimised with subqueries:

```
Select U.UserId as 'Id', 
 U.name as 'Name',
 isnull(fromSummed.sentCount, 0) 'SentCount',
 isnull(ToSummed.ReceivedCount, 0) 'ReceivedCount'
FROM [User] U 
outer apply (select count(*) as sentCount from [Conversation] cFrom where cFrom.FromUserId = 'user1' and ToUserId = U.UserId ) fromSummed
outer apply (select count(*) as ReceivedCount from [Conversation] cTo where cTo.ToUserId = 'user1' and cTo.FromUserId = U.UserId) ToSummed
where isnull(fromSummed.sentCount, 0)>0 or isnull(ToSummed.ReceivedCount, 0)>0
```

Comment: this select would to through all users in your DB and check if 'user1' sent messages to him/her. You can add a where clause to exclude rows where sent and received are both null or 0.

Comment: not working having syntax error. I am using ms sql 2008. is it because of that ?

Comment: @NileshMistry Please always specify up front if you are using an unsupported version of SQL Server. Without that detail, the prevailing assumption will be that you are using software from the most recent decade.

Comment: @AaronBertrand ok

Comment: i corrected the query. i needed the tables to test compilation. please check now. It is 2008 compatible